# Dynamic list of tables / function GetCell(tableId, row, col) /function GetTableId(cell)

Tags: javascript, html

A question about a dynamic list of HTML [tables](https://divtable.com/generator/):

How should the HTML be extended so that the tabel-Id can generally be accessed from the cell and vice versa via the tabel-Id the cell of this table can be accessed?

For this purpose, each cell should be given a unique marker. Each table should use the same markers for its cells. Can the cell be given an attribute *cell = "c_row_col"* for this purpose?

What would the JavaScript function look like for returning the associated DOM element cell or table?